# How to get bitbucket OAUTH token via bash script?

Tags: bash, oauth, bitbucket

I am attempting to get an OAUTH token for bitbucket via a bash script.

At the moment, I'm able to use the following URL:
`https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize?client_id={key}&response_type=token` 
I simply visit this via a web browser and hit authenticate, I am then redirected to the callback website, And I can see the token in the URL. For example, if my callback url was stackoverflow.com, My url bar would now contain `stackoverflow.com/#access_token=XYZ`

What I need to do, is figure out how to hit this url but get this access token in a bash script rather than from a URL.

Relevant doc: https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize?client_id=kdBELaEX6HkUexPMRS&response_type=token

Comment: Why are you using OAUTH and not the other authentication methods that are for non-apps?

Answer (score 0):

Using curl (can be used inside your bash script)

```
curl -X POST https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token \
  -d grant_type=client_credentials \ 
  -u  key:secret
```